# Flask ImportError: cannot import name app

Tags: python, flask

After setting up a simple Flask app from [this](http://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-flask/index.html) tutorial, with a `run.py` file containing:

```
from site import app
import os

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.run(debug=True)
```

I have `site/__init__.py` with

```
from .views import app
from .models import graph
```

And under `site/views.py`

```
from .models import User, get_todays_recent_posts
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
```

with a bunch of `@app.route` functions

`site/models.py` has

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
from passlib.hash import bcrypt
from datetime import datetime
import os
import uuid

graph = Graph()
```

I keep getting a `ImportError: cannot import name app` error on the first line of `run.py`.

All the other questions seem to be a circular import issue, but I'm sure I don't have one.

I haven't created a virtual environment as described in the project, could that be the issue?

I'm using python2.7 on windows.

**EDIT:**

A fix to the problem was to restructure entire project into one .py file, which feels like a cleaner file structure anyway.

Comment: Where is `site/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at [the source code](https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-flask/blob/master/blog/__init__.py)

You'll see in `site/__init__.py`

```
from  .views import app
```

This declares `app` in the `site` module, therefore allowing you to use this at the run module

```
from site import app
```

Otherwise, you need

```
 from site.views import app
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I have the __init__.py file, will edit my answer.

Comment: Okay, but still, you should actually checkout the github source project, then attempt to run it, or make changes from there. Rather than restructure or build from scratch Plus, all new Python development should use Python3

Comment: Probably should have taken that route. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

`app` is defined within `site.views`, so you need to import it from there.

```
from site.views import app
```

Comment: What if `import app from views` is in `site/__init__.py`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I have the __init__.py file, added to question, but no, code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If people are still having this issue, changing the folder name from site to something else (e.g. website) and when you import from site change it to the new folder name works.

I suppose there is something in Flask that prevents you from naming your directory site.